How to export search results using Find and Replace in LibreOffice Calc
We have an ODS file with two spreadsheets. (Picture 1)
We are able to use ‘Find All’ to locate cells containing the string ‘Steve’. (Picture 2)
However, we are unable to copy them. Because they are on two different spreadsheeds



Is it possible to achieve this somehow?" (Picture 3)
Brief: We need to copy all rows on all spreadsheets that includes string
I can partially achieve what I want using LibreOffice Base.
With SQL, I’m able to retrieve all cells containing 'Steve', but only within a single spreadsheet.
I need a better solution that works across all spreadsheets.
My idea is: The Find and Replace button can modify all matches at once.
Would it be possible to use a regex or a similar approach to 'mark' all matches as selected?
For example:
Find: Steve
Replace: select_line(%Steve%)
This way, it could effectively identify and process all occurrences in a structured way."**
I need such a solution if possible
Please note: I tried with Macro as well. But it was working soooo slow. Something that works faster might work as well.
